# Fixing deprecation with boundingRectWithSize CGRectMake

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

So I'm trying to fix some outstanding, pre-IOS7 deprecations involving sizeWithFont.  I've been following the answers provided here ['sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:'is deprecated:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922252/sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmodeis-deprecated)

..which mostly have to deal with CGSize and CGSizeMake. But *my* problem has to do with CGRectMake and I haven't quite been able to put it together the way that I want.

Here's the original code:

```
CGSize optimumSize = [percentageText sizeWithFont:self.percentageFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(max_text_width,100)];
CGRect percFrame = CGRectMake(text_x, right_label_y, optimumSize.width, optimumSize.height);
```

And here's what I've tried to do:

```
NSString *percentageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", component.value/total*100];
                NSAttributedString *attributedText =
                [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                 initWithString:percentageText
                 attributes:@
                 {
                 NSFontAttributeName: self.percentageFont
                 }];
                CGRect percFrame = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGRectMake(text_x, right_label_y, max_text_width,100))
                                                                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                context:nil];

                CGSize optimumSize = percFrame.size;
```

But I get the error: "Sending CGRect to parameter of incompatible type CGSize". However I need all four attributes... not just the width and height. So I *have* to use CGRect and not CGSize. Any idea how I can make it work?

Otherwise all of my other code that just uses CGSize works just fine. It's just I have two pieces of code that really need CGRect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method on NSAttributedString takes a maximum size as argument. You can set the origin you want on the CGRect it returns.

```
NSString *percentageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", component.value/total*100];
            NSAttributedString *attributedText =
            [[NSAttributedString alloc]
             initWithString:percentageText
             attributes:@
             {
             NSFontAttributeName: self.percentageFont
             }];
            CGRect percFrame = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSizeMake(max_text_width,100))
                                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                            context:nil];
            percFrame.origin = CGPointMake(text_x, right_label_y)
```

Comment: They have GOT to come up with a way to streamline this... somehow what was 2 lines of code is now 10 lines of code.  I would've done something in the backend to make it as efficient (or more efficient) as it was before it was deprecated.  Anyway your answer works.  Thanks!